# Update object field by doing sum of another object field data

Tags: trigger

I have 2 objects, parent and child. They have a master detail relationship. Child has a field called `Expenses__c` and parent has a field called `My_Total_Expenses__c`.

I want to show the total sum of `Expenses__c` field in the parent `My_Total_Expenses__c` field. In the parent object there is also a rollup summary field in which summarised object is child and field to aggregate is `Expenses__c`.

I have written this code but it is throwing while inserting the data. I am calling this code in a trigger.

```
public class PapaBachaController {
    public static void oninsert(List<Child__c> ch){
        set<double> bc= new set<double>();
        for(Child__c c:ch){
            if(c.Expenses__c !=null){
                bc.add(c.Expenses__c);
            }
        }
        List<Parent__c> ul=new List<Parent__c>();
        List<aggregateresult> ar=[select sum(Expenses__c) from Child__c];

        if(ar.size()>0){
            for(aggregateresult results:ar){

            Parent__c a=new Parent__c();
            a.My_total_expenses__c=(double)results.get('Expenses__c');
            ul.add(a);
            }
        }
        if(ul.size()>0){
            update ul;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You already have master detail relastionship,  and you are already using roll up summary field on parent, why you need to write code for aggregation of expenses?

Answer (score 0):

You should place an **alias** just after the aggregation like:

```
ar=[select sum(Expenses__c)myAliasName from Child__c]
```

Then you could access the aggregation result using:

```
a.My_total_expenses__c=(double)results.get('myAliasName');
```

If you are not using aliasing, then a **default name is being assigned**. It starts as **expr0** and continues till **exprN**. In your case is the following:

```
a.My_total_expenses__c=(double)results.get('expr0');
```

More info in:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm

Comment: a.My_total_expenses__c=(double)results.get('expr0')  could anyone define the line that what it is doing?

Comment: @user10253353, you have to either use alias names or auto-generated (indexed by position) names to access the "fields" retrieved in an aggregate result. This line gets the first (unaliased) "field" from the aggregate result. Note, however, I believe Radhe Radhe's comment on the question is right and you should be using a rollup.

Comment: i am trying to do it manually through trigger and i have completed that